# Best way to program piecewise-linear function on DSP TMS320C5509

Tags: c++, math, signal-processing

There is a Table of pairs , which defines pieces bounds.
And we are using straightforward algorithm:

y = f(x)

1. Calculate index n in Table using x
2. Get Yn and Yn+1, compute linear interpolation Y

Y is the answer.

So i think, there must be more efficient method, could you please point me?

Comment: More efficient compared to what? Show us some code.

Comment: what is purpose of algorithm?

Comment: J. Calleja, Yes, x-values are equally spaced. Moreover, the Table has length  that is power of 2, so that n could be calculated very simply.
dirkgently, I meant, that answer would include some «best practice» algorithm. And I don't want to concentrate on details, therefore I didn't give code.

Comment: So, n can be calculated in O(1), Yn, Yn+1 and Y too, so what kind of efficiency improvement do you expect?

Comment: Yep, it is. I didn't thought about that.
Maybe I've written not exactly what i meant. I also want some precision improvement without harming speed.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number and distribution of pairs, you might be able to instead store a table T containing only the Y values at regular intervals.  Pick the interval to be a power of 2: i=2^c.  Then for a given X:

```
n=X>>c;
Y= T[n]
Y+= ((T[n+1]-T[n])* (X&(i-1))>>c;
```

This should work as long as you have space for a table with small enough intervals to catch sudden changes in the slope of Y, and enough headroom in Y for the multiply.

Answer (score 0):

Use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) for step 1.

EDIT: due to the comment you added afterwards, this is not necessary, since your intervals are equally spaced.